# DataGridView index

Tags: datagridview

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. I have a problem whith DataGridView trying to prevent the index from returning to the first cell and the persistence of the selected cell.

When the update is due cursor to the first cell

I did this to stop it

```
Private Sub DataGridView100_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView100.RowsAdded


    DataGridView100.Columns(0).Selected = False
    DataGridView100.Rows(0).Selected = False
    DataGridView100.Rows(0).Cells(0).Selected = False

    'Another way

    'DataGridView100.ClearSelection()

End Sub
```

What I want now: when I select a cell or a column to stay in the selected choice

The second question
Also want if the number changes within the cell to change the background of that cell

Answer (score 0):

This is in C# but probably you will be to do the simillar thing.

First: Change background color:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 // your code here
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red
}
```

Do you need the condition that it changes only when number in cell have changed? Do you need to triger change with manual change of cell content or by programmatic change?

Second: Save the selection

First store the selected row index:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
  nSelectedRowIndex = e.RowIndex;

}
```

Then in your `DataGridView100_RowsAdded`:

```
// your code

dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView1.Rows[nSelectedRowIndex].Selected = true
```

This Works for selected Row, you can store the selected cell index and than add `.Cells[nSelectedCellIndex.Selected = true`.